# Make set of fields required or non-required dynamicaly in DRF

Tags: django-rest-framework

For example I have following serializer:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    field1 = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    field2 = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    field3 = serializers.CharField(required=True)

    field4 = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    field5 = serializers.CharField(required=False)
```

First 3 fields are required but last 2 are not.
What I want to do if when only 3 **required** fields are present in raw data that’s fine, but as soon as **field4** or **field5**  is present in raw data I want all fields with   `required=False` turns to  `required=True`, that is if I input any non-required fields, all other non-required fields would become required.

I another words, I anjust it in a way that i could input zero of non-required fields  or all of them.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created following mixin to solve this issue:

```
class RequiredTogetherFieldsMixin:
    """
    Allow to specify few fields as required together. They are not required until at leas one field from
    this set is filled with data. That would trigger all other fields specified in 'required_together_fields'
    became required. That is ine can leave all required together fields empty or fill tem all.
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if not self.fields.keys() >= set(self.required_together_fields):
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                {'required_together_fields': error_codes.REQUIRED_TOGETHER_WRONG_FIELDS_NAMES},
                code='wrong_required_together_fields'
            )

        required_fields_in_data = set(self.required_together_fields).intersection(self.initial_data)

        if required_fields_in_data:
            for field_name, field in self.fields.items():
                if field_name in self.required_together_fields:
                    field.required = True

    required_together_fields = ()
```

All you need to do is to specify `required_together_fields` in your serializer and inherit from this mixin of cource. 
As soon at leas one of the fields is filed with data, all other fields would became `required` as well.